# Picker with Fetchrequest

Tags: swiftui, picker, fetchrequest

I have some trouble with pickers with Fetchrequest. I can display a list but can't manage the picker.

```
struct DepenseView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: []) var TypeDepenses: FetchedResults<TypeDepense>
    @State var selectedDepense : String = "Autre"
       
    var body: some View {
        List {
                ForEach(TypeDepenses) { typb in
                    Text(typb.type ?? "Unknown Title")
                }
        }
            
        List {
            Picker("Type", selection: $selectedDepense){
                ForEach(TypeDepenses){ type in
                    Text(type.type ?? "Unknown Title").tag(type.type)
                }
                Text("Autre").tag("Autre")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add .tag with different possibilities (.tag(type), .tag(type.type), .tag(type.id), ...). I just want the picker list to be different type from the data base. I can see them but I can't select them.

Comment: The `tag` must be **unique** (the nil-coalesced `type` is not)  and must be the same type as the `selection`. And two `Text` lines in a `ForEach` body make no sense anyway.

Comment: Yes of course, I just put the second Text outside the ForEach, my bad. But it is still not working.

Comment: `type.type` is obviously an optional but `selectedDepense` is a non-optional. That's not the same type.

Comment: Okay so I should make selectedDepense optional (how can I do that ?) or type.type non optional ? I don't really understand what an optional is

Comment: Never mind, just solved it !